# Fingering for right hand thirds in Bluebird by Alexis Ffrench

Tags: piano, fingering

[image]

Hi, I'm trying to figure out how to play this part of the song (Bluebird by Alexis Ffrench). It seems impossible (for an amateur) to play it with proper rhythm. Could anyone please show me the fingering for right hand? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for response. Here you go: http://bit.ly/2Yo1Fls

Comment: Hand shape and size affects fingerings for thirds a great deal. Can you manage 42 51 42 31 | 42 31 42 51 42 54 | 42 for the first phrase?

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. I will try your option and get back here to confirm :)

Comment: OK, i got it :) The only problem for now is 54 but I'll manage. Thank you very much for your help. You saved me couple of hours of frustration ;)

Comment: Note that since the pedal is down, you don't need gluey legato and can jump to a more comfortable fingering on that last third if 54 doesn't suit you. It will still sound legato so long as you're light with the hand.

Comment: Pedalling through it all isn't the best idea - is it?

Comment: @Tim I don't know the piece but it looks like it would sound gruesome if you did. I just meant that the last two thirds in the bar are on the same harmony so the pedal can help out.

Comment: @replete - not a criticism of your answer, just a comment about the pedal mark being 8 bars minimum, with different harmonies all 'blending' into one mush.

Comment: Incidentally, a similar run of fast thirds occurs in piano adaptations of Pachelbel's Canon, which might provide a nice familiar comparison if someone wants to write up an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think your notation is for the part starting at...

Except for this passage *all the rest of the RH* is single notes not double notes. I'm a little suspicious that the recording was multi-tracked so that the accompaniment part is one track and the treble part is another track. When the treble part track gets to the part in thirds it *may* be performed with two hands.

Playing the passage with one hand presents a fingering problem, because it moves around points where the hand changes position and the fingers must cross over each other.

I think one approach to playing it is focus the fingering around the 'shake' parts, the parts where two notes are alternated rapidly. I put those two passages in boxes...

[image]

...both are centered around tones `C5 Eb5` but the first shake involves the tones below and the second the tones above.

The first shake, in `Eb` major RH `C Eb` to `Bb D` normally is a position change `13 35`. That's a really inconvenient place to perform a shake so I tried alternate fingering `24 13`.

The second shake, `C Eb` *up* to `D F` fall on the usual `Eb` major fingering `13 24`.

After managing the shakes the trick is to get up in position for `Eb G` to `G Bb`. There doesn't seem to be a good way to do that other than just a quick hand shift. I opted for placing the thumb on the `Eb` for `13 35`, but it seems like `24 45` could be used too.

That my attempt at a fingering.

I tried watching the pianist's hands in the video, but his hands are obscured by his back during this passage!

I would really love to know how it was executed on the recording.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things to take into consideration when looking for fingering with thirds. Always use finger combinations that where there is a finger in-between like 53, 42, and 31. The other finger combination you can use is 21. Place your hand with 53 at the highest note. In this case I would put 53 on the G and E flat and then use my other fingers. You'll have to shift hand placement to reach the G and B flat at the end of the phrase. To make this hand shift you should use 13 and 12 to move up. This can be done by using 13 and 12 instead of 13 and 24. On the fourth measure I would use 35 for E flat and C. Then 12 for B flat and D then 13 for C and E flat, then 12 for DF and then position your hand for the other notes.